# Copy plain text with no rich styles to clipboard without losing focus?

Tags: javascript, html, focus, selection, clipboard

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099409/copy-to-clipboard-as-plain-text) where it is asked for a way to simply copy text as plain text. I want to do exactly that but with one additional thing - not lose focus on the current element.

I need this for a Chrome extension, so I'm not bothered with cross-browser support. When the user types in an input (or `contenteditable`), a dropdown with choices appears. If he chooses one of them, it is copied to his clipboard. I don't want the element to lose focus because some sites might have implemented logic to run on the element's `blur` event.

Here's what I've tried:

### Solution 1

Create an `<input>` element and use its `select()` method:

```js
function clipWithInput(text) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    document.body.appendChild(input);

    input.addEventListener("focus", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    input.value = text;
    input.select();

    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(input);
}

document.getElementById("choice").onmousedown = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevents loss of focus when clicked
  clipWithInput("Hello");
};
```

```css
#main {background: #eee;}
#choice {background: #fac;}
```

```html
<div id="main" contenteditable="true">Focus this, click the div below and then paste here.</div>
<div id="choice">Click to add "Hello" to clipboard</div>
```

As you can see, this works. The text is copied. However, when you focus the `contenteditable` and click on the "choice", the focus is lost. The choice element has `preventDefault()` on its `mousedown` event which causes it to not break focus. The dummy `<input>` element is the problem here, even though it has `preventDefault()` on its `focus` event. I **guess** the problem here is that it's too late - the initial element has already fired its `blur`, so my dummy input's `focus` is irrelevant.

### Solution 2

Use a dummy text node and the Selection API:

```js
function clipWithSelection(text) {
    var node = document.createTextNode(text),
        selection = window.getSelection(),
        range = document.createRange(),
        clone = null;

    if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
        clone = selection.getRangeAt(selection.rangeCount - 1).cloneRange();
    }

    document.body.appendChild(node);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    range.selectNodeContents(node);
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");

    selection.removeAllRanges();
    document.body.removeChild(node);

    if (clone !== null) {
        selection.addRange(clone);
    }
}

document.getElementById("choice").onmousedown = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevents loss of focus when clicked
  clipWithSelection("Hello");
};
```

```css
#main {background: #eee;}
#choice {background: #fac;}
```

```html
<div id="main" contenteditable="true">Focus this, click the div below and then paste here.</div>
<div id="choice">Click to add "Hello" to clipboard</div>
```

This works perfectly at first glance. The text is copied, no focus is lost, the caret stays at the same position. No drama. However, when you paste the text in a `contenteditable` (like Gmail's email composer), this is the result:

```
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: "Times New Roman"; font-size: medium;">Hello</span>
```

Not plain text.

- I tried appending the element in the `<head>` where there are no styles - nope. Text isn't selected and nothing is copied.
- I tried appending the text node in a `<span>` and set stuff like `style.fontFamily` to `inherit`, as well as `fontSize` and `color`. Still doesn't work. I logged the dummy element and it correctly had my `inherit` styles. However, the pasted text didn't.

### Recap

I want to **programmatically** copy **plain text** with **no styles** while **preserving focus** on the currently active element.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution (especially 2) was okay. When you paste in a `contenteditable`, it needs to be expected that there are span codes inserted, many use that in `insertHTML`. You are not to expect plain text programmatically. Some would suggest not using a `contenteditable` at all (though I understand you're talking about some extension). But your solution is more compatible with mobiles than MDN or such.

So, you programmatically copy plain with no style added (if no `contenteditable`) while preserving focus on the current element.